# No line break when passing value containing "\n" received from server side to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## No line break when \n is passed as initial value of textarea

### problem

```
<TextArea
  defaultValue={text} // "text" is the string received from the server side
  ...
```

[image]

### verification

- Success if I pass the initial value directly on the client side instead of the value received from the server side

```
<TextArea
  defaultValue={"hogehoge\n\nhugahuga\n\n"}
  ...
```

[image]

### library & Framework

- React.js
- axios
- styled-components

Comment: could you reproduce your problem on codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a native browser `textarea` include a carriage return

```
<TextArea
  defaultValue={text.replace('\\n', '\r\n')}
```

---

If you are using a `contenteditable` component, replace `\n` with `<br />`, and after you fetch it later on from the server, React will not immediately output your `<br />` tags as HTML.

You will need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) in order for the `<br />` elements to reflect in the front-end as HTML elements.

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in
> the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
> it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting
> (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have
> to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html
> key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. For example:

This assumes